# How to hide all the images on a page are defined through CSS background-image

Tags: image, hide, background-image

I need to hide all the images on the page So I wrote this code :

```
var imagesVisibility = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imagesVisibility.length; i++) {
    imagesVisibility[i].style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
}
```

It works great but I can not hide the images are defined via CSS.
How do I hide all images on a page are defined via CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the jQuery, which has a css method which lets you alter the styles of a selected element:

```
$(‘#idofthediv’).css({backgroundImage:’none’});
```